# not able to extract links from the following html

Tags: html, swift, tfhpple

I need to grab the link from certain link to perform crawling however I can't extract the link from the html no matter how many time I rewrite the xpath. Hence, I'm not able to find a way to extract the link from it. Please give some suggestion to me to solve the problem.

This is the html code for the link that I'm gonna to extract the link from:

```
<div class="" id="subject1" datacallname="主题_同类主题" params="{'catid':'12','sid':'336'}" isload="1" style="">
  <ul class="rail-list">
    <li>
      <cite class="start0" style="height:16px;">
      </cite>
      <a href="http://www.gorate.com.my/item-386.html">the Library&nbsp;@&nbsp;Leisure Ma
      </a>
    </li>
```

how I can extract the link `"//*[@id="subject1"]/ul/li[1]/a/@href"` and the website

I gonna to scrape the link form : http://www.gorate.com.my/item-336.html#.Vhx55BOqqkr

Comment: Do you want to extract all links in the html?

Comment: Yes @Qbyte, so do you have any idea on this?

Comment: Your xpath looks ok. ([screenshot](https://www.evernote.com/l/AOwS_Nup6ldLXqsAJRpnjwu62sg4Nd3CP5c))

Comment: but im not able to retrieve the link from there